# update not working during batch insert in TDengine database

Tags: tdengine

I created a database with update=1, so that I can update some records based on the timestamp. but I found the update is not working when I use batch insert. I also tried normal insert, updating record is working.

```sql
Welcome to the TDengine shell from Linux, Client Version:2.1.7.2
Copyright (c) 2020 by TAOS Data, Inc. All rights reserved.

taos> create database test update 1;
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.007977s)

taos> use test;
Database changed.

taos> create table tb(ts timestamp, c1 int);
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.015282s)

taos> insert into tb values(now, 1)(now, null);
Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.000797s)

taos> select * from tb;
           ts            |     c1      |
========================================
 2021-09-28 11:37:32.339 |           1 |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.002671s)

taos> insert into tb values("2021-09-28 11:37:32.339", null);
Query OK, 1 of 1 row(s) in database (0.000611s)

taos> select * from tb;
           ts            |     c1      |
========================================
 2021-09-28 11:37:32.339 |        NULL |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.002591s)
```

what is the difference between batch insert and normal insert in TDengine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch insertion uses the same "now". It leads two records to use the same timestamp which is not possible to be a valid record as the time-series database needs each record to use a different timestamp.